# iOS NSLocale.CurrentLocale.CountryCode Returning language instead of country code

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm building a xamarin ios application, and I'm willing to know the current user's country code, but the country code returned always matches the language of the device.

To get the language code, I use : "NSLocale.CurrentLocale.CountryCode"

Can anyone please tell me how to get the country code independent of the language ?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, [the current locale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/#locale) can be queried by either of two ways:

- NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier
- NSLocale.AutoUpdatingCurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier

The first value can be cached by the operating system and so might not always reflect the user’s currently selected locale. Use the second value to obtain the currently selected locale.

**Therefore**, you need to use **NSLocale.AutoUpdatingCurrentLocale.CountryCode** instead of **NSLocale.CurrentLocale.CountryCode** to get the current country code.Then it will work.